# How to pre checked a specific item in a list when a listview being created?

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, checkedtextview

I want to pre checked/ pre selected a specific item when a list being created. I use CheckedTextView for the text and checkbox.

For example, I have 3 items, after the list create, I will get a listview. and the second item is already check/tick.

I know how to perform it by using onclick, but what I need is before I click it. some item is already checked.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean `isChecked` variable in your ItemModel, set true/false as you wish. Check/uncheck item in your CustomAdapter.

Comment: Am I place it into my adapter's getView()? For example I need to check/tick the item in position[2], where should I add this code?

Comment: Do you know how to create a custom ListView? If don't, please read it: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92